# How to perform count(userid) and count(userid) when direct_access = yes in single sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written

```
with s as (select count(userid)as total_id,date from a), 
U as (
  select count(userid) as direct_access_count, date 
  where direct_access = 'Yes'
)
Select s.total_id, u.direct_access_count from s join u on s.date = u.date
```

Please help me to achieve total_id and direct_access_count in only one SQL query instead of something that I written above.Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please edit the question, show complete table definition, example data and expected output

Comment: 'date' is a reserved word in oracle, so I do hope your usage of it as a column name is just pseudo-code.  Even as just an example, it's best not to confuse the example with the incorrect use of reserved words.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , Gibbs. Date is just a pseudo - word here. And what is meant is getting count(userid) as total_count and count(userid when direct _access = Yes) as direct_access_count in single query. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean something like this:

```sql
select
  date,
  count(userid) as total_id,
  count(case when direct_access = 'Yes' then 1 end) as direct_access_count
from a
group by date
```

The `CASE` evaluates to a non-null (I used the value 1 here; could be anything) if direct_access = 'Yes'. The non-null value is counted. If direct_access <> 'Yes' the `CASE` evaluates to null and is not counted.